# Is it possible to set postgres search_path in node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm moving an application from RoR to Express.js.
ActiveRecord postgres adapter has the search_path configuration option.

Is it possible to set the search_path for the Client ?

Comment: You can always send `SET search_path = '...'` commands.

Comment: [There is a number of ways to set the `search_path`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)'

Answer (score 2):

My preference would be to chance this on the database or user if possible.

```
ALTER [DATABASE or USER] [name] set search_path='[searchpath]'
```

If that fails you can always make sure your search path is set by building into your connection logic:

```
SET search_path='[searchpath]'
```

That will set it on the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes sure you can automaticaly triger `SET` command "on" connection event

```
pool.on('connect', (client) => {
  client.query('SET search_path TO schema,public');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
process.env.PGOPTIONS="-c search_path=some_schema"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.